# Lebesgue-integrability of the Dirac delta function?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, dirac-delta

I stumbled upon [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522603) question, which I think was answered incorrectly. Considering the Dirac delta function
$$
\delta\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty],x\mapsto\begin{cases}\infty,&\text{if }x=0,\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
as a mapping from $\mathbb R$ to $[0,\infty]$ (which is perfectly well-defined) and NOT as a distribution $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ or $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$. I commonly see people use the sequence $\delta_n:=n\cdot1_{[-\frac1{2n},\frac1{2n}]}$ to "prove" $\int\delta\,d\lambda=1$, but this sequence isn't even increasing. If this argument actually holds, what prevents me from using $\delta_n:=\alpha\cdot n\cdot1_{[-\frac1{2n},\frac1{2n}]},\alpha>0$ to "prove" $\int\delta\,d\lambda=\alpha$? **Now my question is whether or not the *function* $\delta$ as defined above is actually Lebesgue-integrable?** Here's my shot at proving that it is Lebesgue-integrable (maybe I just missed some detail):

> $\delta\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty]$ is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-$\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$-measurable, because we have $$\delta^{-1}(\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R}))=\{\emptyset,\{0\},\mathbb R\setminus\{0\},\mathbb R\}\subseteq\mathcal B(\mathbb R).$$ Furthermore $\delta_n:=n\cdot1_{\{0\}}\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty[$ is a simple function (non-negative, bounded, measurable and has finite image) for every $n\geq1$ and the sequence $(\delta_n)_{n\geq1}$ is monotonically increasing, converges pointwise to $\delta$ and it holds that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int\delta_nd\lambda=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\underbrace{\lambda(\{0\})}_{=0}=0<\infty.$$ Hence, $\delta$ is Lebesgue-integrable by definition and we have $\int\delta\,d\lambda=0$.

**APPENDIX:** Here is the definition of Lebesgue-integrability that I've learned. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be some measure space. A function $f\colon\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ is called *simple*, if it is $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-measurable and has a finite image, i.e. $f=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i1_{A_i}$ for some $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k\in[0,\infty[$ and $A_1,\dots,A_k\in\mathcal A$ (not necessarily disjoint). It's integral is defined as $\int f\,d\mu:=\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha_i\mu(A_i)\in[0,\infty]$. We then showed that this is well-defined, i.e. independent of the choice of $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ and $A_1,\dots,A_k$. Now let $f\colon\Omega\to[0,\infty]$ be $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$-measurable. We proceeded to show that there exists an increasing sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of simple functions $f_n\colon\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise. We then defined the integral of $f$ to be $\int f\,d\mu:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\mu\in[0,\infty]$ and showed that this is well-defined too, i.e. independent of the choice of $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. We called $f$ integrable, if $\int f\,d\mu<\infty$. A $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$-measurable function $f\colon\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ is called integrable, if $f^+:=f\cdot1_{\{f\geq0\}}\colon\Omega\to[0,\infty]$ and $f^-:=-f\cdot1_{\{f\leq0\}}\colon\Omega\to[0,\infty]$ are integrable. In this case we define $\int f\,d\mu:=\int f^+d\mu-\int f^-d\mu$.

Using this definition, it is easy to show using measure theoretic induction that a $\mathcal A$-$\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$-measurable function $f\colon\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ with $\mu(\{f\neq0\})=0$ is integrable and has integral 0.

$\delta\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty]$ clearly is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$-$\mathcal B(\overline{\mathbb R})$-measurable and satisfies $\lambda(\{\delta\neq0\})=\lambda(\{0\})=0$. Hence $\delta\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty]$ is integrable and $\int\delta\,d\lambda=0$.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} n 1_{[-1/(2n),1/(2n)]}$ is the **definition** of the Dirac delta distribution. This sequence converges in the sense of distributions because for any $\phi \in C^\infty_c$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \phi \ast n 1_{[-1/(2n),1/(2n)]} \in C^\infty$. As you see $\begin{cases}\infty,&\text{if }x=0,\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ doesn't define any distribution uniquely.

Comment: Okay and where does the followong argument break down? Every measurable function that vanishes almost everywhere is Lebesgue-integrable and has integral 0. $\delta$ as defined in my question is measurable and vanishes almost everywhere. Hence, it is Lebesgue-integrable and has integral 0. I can find at least 34 more theorems and propositoons in my Analysis III script (yeah I actually counted them) that imply the integrability of $\delta$ as defined in my question and that it has integral 0.

Comment: Every "measurable function" : $\delta$ isn't a function, it is a distribution. Removing finitely many (or countably many) points of a function doesn't change its $\int$, doing so with $\delta$ does change it, that's the difference.

Comment: @reuns Then take a closer look at how I defined $\delta$. I explicitly stated that I consider the function above mapping $\mathbb R$ to $[0,\infty]$ and not the distribution.

Comment: It is $= 0$ in $L^1$. For Lebesgue integral we are just looking at the measures of sets of the form $\{ x, f(x) \ge M\}$. Here $\{ x, f(x) \ge M\} = \{0\}$ has measure $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of Lebesgue Integrable...

If $\int \delta d \lambda := \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \delta_n d \lambda,$ then, since the limit exists and is 1, $\delta$ is integrable.

However, usually the Lebesgue integral is defined as $$\int \delta d \lambda := \sup\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)\alpha_i \right\},$$ where the $\sup$ runs over all functions $\varphi(t) := \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \cdot 1_{(a_i,b_i)}(t),$ that satisfy $0 \leq \varphi(t) \leq \delta(t).$  (Here $1_S(t)$ is the indicator function of the set $S$.)  In this definition, $\int \delta d \lambda = 0$, so $\delta$ is integrable for a stupid reason: it's 0 [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere).

**PS:**  A generally difficult problem in analysis is to identify when $\lim \int f_n = \int \lim f_n.$  With your $\delta$ and $\delta_n$ functions, you have an example of when the two sides are not equal.

Comment: Why does the limit definition yield $\int\delta\,d\lambda=1$?

Comment: The $n$-th integral in the limit is 1, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1 = 1.$

Comment: Okay, let me ask this differently: Where does my proof outlined in my question break down? I used the following definition of Lebesgue-integrability: A non-negative function $f\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty]$ is called Lebesgue-integrable, if there exists an increasing sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of simple functions $f_n\colon\mathbb R\to[0,\infty[$ such that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges pointwise to $f$ and the sequence $(\int f_nd\lambda)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded. In this case we call $\int f\,d\lambda:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\lambda$ the integral of $f$.

Comment: Just to clarify, I didn't use Lebesgue's Theorem to justify the limit, it is part of the definition of Lebesgue-integrability that I know.

Comment: @Cubinator73 Oh, you are asking us to critique your proof?  The question was unclear.  What you have is just about accurate, except you should really show that ANY sequence $f_n$ satisfying $0 \leq f_n(x) \leq \delta(x)$ has $\lim_n \int f_n = 0$.  Not just $\delta_n$.  But it's pretty much the same argument...

Comment: Do I really need to show this for every such sequence? I remember that we showed that for every measurable non-negative function there exists a increasing sequence of simple function converging pointwise to said function and that the limit of integrals is independent of the choise of the simple functions. I'll better take a look into the script... Still, thank you :)

Comment: "It depends on your definition of Lebesgue Integrable...": Sorry, but that's nonsense. The Lebesgue integral is a standard thing; any two _correct_ versions of the definition are equivalent. In particular a given measurable function is or is not Lebesgue integrable, period

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, I agree.  Was just trying to be pedagogic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course if you define a function $\delta:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty]$ that way then $\delta\in L^1$, because $\delta$ is measurable and $\int|\delta|=0<\infty$.

But this has no relevance whatever to the correctness of that other answwer! That other question is about the object commonly known as the "Dirac delta", and the *function* you defined here is *not* the Dirac delta. (This serves to answer the things you say you're confused about: In each case the confusion arises from assuming that that function *is* the Dirac delta.)

Comment: Well, I tried to distinguish between them by calling them Dirac delta *function* and Dirac delta *distribution* and in addition to that I explicitly stated that I consider the function defined in my question and not the distribution. Though, you are right, I actually thought that the $\delta$ I defined is called Dirac delta function.

Comment: @Cubinator73 Fine. The two are not the same - that other question is about the Dirac delta distribution, so nothing you say about the Dirac delta function has any relevance to that question.

Comment: Okay, just one last thing. The Dirac delta *distribution* $\delta\colon C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)\to\mathbb R,\varphi\mapsto\varphi(0)$ is not regular, meaning there is no $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\mathbb R^d)$ such that $\delta(\varphi)=\int f\varphi d\lambda^d$ for every $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$. Am I right in assuming we still like to write $\delta(\varphi)=\int\varphi f\,d\lambda^d=\varphi(0)$ even though there is no such $f$ that satisfies this property and thus make it a convention?

Comment: Do "we" like to write it that way? Some people do; see millions of posts here that write $\int \phi(t)\delta(t)\,dt$, or various differential equations books. Mathematicians don't - it leads to confusion.