# Prove that there is no integrable function such that $\int_0^1\delta(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x=f(0)$ for every continuous function $f$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove that there is no integrable function $\delta:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $\int_0^1\delta(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x=f(0)$ for every continuous function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: This would be the actual $\delta$ "function". Lookup any book/notes on distributions.

Comment: Maybe you can look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106973/lebesgue-integrability-of-the-dirac-delta-function?rq=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0<a<1$, define 
$$f_a(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}\exp\left(-\dfrac{a^2}{a^2-x^2}\right), & 0\leq x < a\\
0, & x \ge a
\end{array}\right.$$
These are continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and you have that
$$
e^{-1} = f_a(0) = \int_0^{1} \delta(x) f_a(x) dx \leq e^{-1} \int_0^a |\delta(x)| dx
$$

Since the RHS goes to zero as $a\to 0$, you get the contradiction $e^{-1}\leq 0$.

Comment: A function $\delta:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ can be integrable and yet $\int_0^a|\delta(x)|dx=\infty $ for all $a\in (0,1] . $ So can you show that the constraints of the $\delta$ of the Q don't allow that?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet If the property indeed holds, we have that $\int_0^1 \delta(x) dx =1$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet What definition of "integrable" are you thinking of?

Comment: Why are you able to say $\int_0^{1} \delta(x)\, f_a(x)\,dx \leq e^{-1} \int_0^a |\delta(x)|\,dx$?

Comment: @zhw. Suppose $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is continuous on $(0,1]$ with $g(x)>0$ when $1/2n<x<1/(2n-1),$ and $g(x)<0$ when $1/(2n+1)<x< 1/2n,$ for $n\in \Bbb N.$ And $\int_{1/(m+1)}^{1/m}g(x)dx=(-1)^{m+1}/m$ for $m\in \Bbb N.$ And $g(0)=0$... Is $g $ integrable?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It's not Lebesgue integrable and it's not Riemann integrable. The improper Riemann/Lebesgue integrals do exist however

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish When both integrals exist, $\int_I g(x) dx \leq \int_I |g(x)| dx$, so $\int f_a(x) \delta (x) dx \leq \int |f_a(x)| |\delta(x)| dx$. Finally, $f_a(x) = |f_a(x)| \leq f_a(0) = e^{-1}$.